# Request for offline installation assistance for stable-diffusion

Tags: stable-diffusion

I am facing difficulties installing the stable-diffusion package due to unstable internet connectivity. I was wondering if there is a way to download all necessary files using a download manager like Internet Download Manager (IDM) for offline installation.

Additionally, I encountered the following error while trying to install Pinokio:

**Error: Response status was 416
at ClientRequest. (C:\Users\S.M.N\AppData\Local\Programs\Pinokio\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-downloader-helper\dist\index.js:1:9499)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:693:27)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:117:17)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:534:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)**

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this issue.

Thank you in advance for your time and support.

Best regards

I tried to install Pinokio